# MUI set different opacity for Chip label/icon and background

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, opacity

I am trying to set on MUI Chip different opacity for label/icon and background.
My goal is to create Chip with: label & icon opacity = 1, background opacity = 0.0571.
Technologies in project: React, TS, MUI V5, Go.

My code:

```
export default function InvoiceItem({ data, func }: Props) {
    return (

    {data.map((invoice, index: number) => (

        <Chip
        label={capitalizeFirstLetter(invoice.status)}
        color={func(invoice.status)}
        sx={{
            mr: 5,
            width: 100,
            typography: "h4",
           }}
        icon={<FiberManualRecordIcon />}
        ></Chip>
    ))}
    );
}
```

I have tried already:
1.

```
<Chip
label={capitalizeFirstLetter(invoice.status)}
color={func(invoice.status)}
opacity= 0.057
sx={{
    "& .MuiChip-label": {
    opacity: 1},
}}
icon={<FiberManualRecordIcon />}
> 
</Chip>
```

2. 

```
sx={{
    "& .MuiChip-root”: {
    opacity: 0.0571
},

    "& .MuiChip-label": {
    opacity: 1
},
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because the parent element's opacity affects the child. To achieve this in a different way rather do something like the following:

```
"& .MuiChip-root”: {
    background-color: rgb(100 100 100 / 0.057)
},
```

The RGB values would of course have to match your original color.

Comment: I found that solution but it doesn't match to my case, as color depends on status of invoice (paid, pending, draft). So I can not use static color :/ @h101

Comment: Your other option is to remove the child from the parent element and then overlay it using absolute positioning.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Last question, does every mui element has the same rule when it comes to opacity? I mean to change chip to MuiButton for example.

Comment: It's not a MUI rule, it's a CSS rule. If a parent has opacity applied, that will automatically apply down the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the background color with rgba value.

```
<Chip
  label={capitalizeFirstLetter(invoice.status)}
  // color={func(invoice.status)}
  icon={<MdFiberManualRecord />}
  sx={{
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0571)",
    color: "black",
  }}
/>
```

This way you don't need to define the color for both label and icon. You can also use the "backgroundColor" value with your "func(invoice.status)" but make that function returns rgba value.